# Python code looping when I don't want it to

Tags: python

```
x = 0
while True:
  choice = int(input ("Choose 1 or 2"))

  if choice == 2:
    print("You chose 2")
    x == 1
  if choice == 1:
    print("You chose 1")
    x == 1
  if choice >2: 
    print("I said 1 or 2.")
    x == 0
  if choice <1:
    print("I said 1 or 2")
    x == 0
```

So if I choose 1 or 2 I want it to stop but if I choose otherwise I want it to loop but it's looping always no matter what could somebody help with this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the suggestions in this thread, [how to ask for a valid user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several errors in it.

`While True` will do exactly that: it will loop until `True` becomes `False`. The problem is that your code has no way of doing that, i.e. looping infinitely.

You can either use `break` after a successful input, as other answers have already provided, or you can do something like this:

```
x = 0
flag = True

while flag:
    choice = int(input('Choose 1 or 2: '))
    if choice in [1, 2]:
        print('You chose', choice)
        x = choice
        flag = False
    else:
        print('I said 1 or 2.')
```

Initially a the boolean `flag` is set to True. The `while` loop checks the condition and sees that `flag` is set to true, so it enters the loop.

The user's input will be taken, assigned to variable `choice`, and `if choice in [1, 2]:` is an easy way of checking if the input is either `1` or `2`. It checks if `choice` matches any element of the list `[1, 2]`. If so, then the user's input is valid.

On successful input, you assign the input to `x` and then set the flag to False. The next iteration of the `while` loop will again check the condition, but see that `flag` is set to False, and will break itself out of the loop.

An invalid input will print but will keep `flag` to True, initiating another iteration of the loop.

Your code also includes `x == 0` where you meant `x = 0`. What you are intending to do is assign a value to variable `x`, but `==` is a boolean operator that checks for equality between two boolean expressions. You want to use the assign operator `=` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You do have to explicitly `break` out of an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    choice = int(input("Choose 1 or 2")) 
    if choice in (1, 2):
        print("You chose {}".format(choice))
        break
    print("I said 1 or 2")
```

Also note that `x == 1` is not an assignment, but a boolean expression which - on its own - doesn't do anything, except raise an error if `x` isn't defined.

Comment: yeah, and how do you memorize the result after that?

Answer (score 1):

As written your code has an infinite `while True` loop. The loop condition is fixed and there are no `break` statements, so naturally it loops forever.

1. If your goal is to quit when `x == 1` then you need to test for that in your loop condition. `while True` will never stop. Make sure you're *assigning* to `x` with `x = 1` -- one equals sign.

   ```
   x = 0
   while not x:
     choice = int(input ("Choose 1 or 2"))

     if choice == 2:
       print("You chose 2")
       x = 1
     if choice == 1:
       print("You chose 1")
       x = 1
     if choice >2: 
       print("I said 1 or 2.")
     if choice <1:
       print("I said 1 or 2")
   ```
2. Alternatively, you could explicitly `break` out of the loop. Then you wouldn't even need `x`.

   ```
   while True:
     choice = int(input ("Choose 1 or 2"))

     if choice == 2:
       print("You chose 2")
       break
     if choice == 1:
       print("You chose 1")
       break
     if choice >2: 
       print("I said 1 or 2.")
     if choice <1:
       print("I said 1 or 2")
   ```
3. A third option is to check `choice` in the loop condition.

   ```
   choice = None
   while choice not in {1, 2}:
     choice = int(input ("Choose 1 or 2"))

     if choice == 2:
       print("You chose 2")
     if choice == 1:
       print("You chose 1")
     if choice >2: 
       print("I said 1 or 2.")
     if choice <1:
       print("I said 1 or 2")
   ```

There's some unnecessary repetition. I'd advise refactoring the checks a bit to eliminate duplicate code.

```
while True:
  choice = int(input("Choose 1 or 2"))

  if choice in {1, 2}:
    break
  else:
    print("I said 1 or 2.")

print("You chose " + str(choice))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add break statements

```
x = 0
while True:
  choice = int(input ("Choose 1 or 2"))

  if choice == 2:
    print("You chose 2")
    x=1
    break
  if choice == 1:
    print("You chose 1")
    x=1
    break 
  if choice >2: 
    print("I said 1 or 2.")
    x=0
  if choice <1:
    print("I said 1 or 2")
    x=0
```

Comment: Change the `x ==`

Comment: @cricket_007 didnt observed that, just focused on adding break to exit from the loop which actually asked by OP